# Get Missing Month

Tags: sql

I have result set like

```
DT_START      DT_END            
 ------------- ----------- 
 2013-05-01    2014-04-01       
 2014-07-01    2015-04-01       
 2014-11-01    2015-02-01
```

i have start date and end date.i need missing month of 2014 in both dates.
Like missing month in 2014 is 5 and 6 (it is the difference between first row "DT_END"  and second row "DT_START")

Comment: clarify i/o. how missing month in 2014 is 5 and 6 and ....

Comment: start date and end date is date range.i want know in these range which month of 2014 is missing or not covered.

Comment: Are you really using mysql, oracle, sql-server-2008 and db2? Spamming tags won't make your question any better; on the contrary it makes it worse as the question most likely requires a solution tailored for the specific db...

Comment: You need a help table with year/month values.

Comment: @jpw i need solution in any database

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

Create a calendar table or make a query that returns all the months between the lowest dt_start and the highest dt_end. How you do this will depend on the actual database you use - some have nice functions that you can use to create sequences, some have number tables etc.

Then use that as source and do a left join with your table and filter out the rows where dt_start is null.

```
select month from all_months -- this is the table/query with all months
left join your_table on month between dt_start and dt_end
where dt_start is null
```